# React-Native Android - Api to find if the app is in foreground or background

Tags: android, react-native

Is it possible to find if the app is in foreground or background in React-Native Android platform? please point me to some reference code.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

ActivityManager-->getRunningAppProcesses--> check every one if your app belongs it